# A reference on Kodaira-Spencer deformation theory

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

I am looking for an introduction to Kodaira-Spencer deformation theory. I have a background in Teichmüller theory, but I know almost nothing of (and am not so interested in) algebraic geometry.

Do you have any good reference ?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the book "Complex manifolds and deformation of complex structures" by Kodaira. The necessary background on sheaves, their cohomology etc. is developed there as well I think.

Comment: @Rieux thanks, i'll have a look